# Minimizing whitespace around plots when using tikzDevice in R

Tags: r, latex, pdflatex, tikz

I use `tikzDevice` in R to write `tikz` code to place plots in LaTeX documents. I have found that the whitespace around the plots, i.e. the margins, is usually excessive.

Here is a minimal example of exporting a R plot as tikz code :

```
x <- seq(30, 70)
probs <- dbinom(x, size=100, prob=0.5)
library(tikzDevice)
tikz('binomial.tex', standAlone = T, width=3, height=2.5)
barplot(names.arg=x, probs, cex.names=0.6, cex.axis=0.6)
dev.off()
```

Running `pdflatex binomial.tex` gives you a small pdf where, as you can see, the is a lot of whitespace in the margins. Ideally, I would like there to be no whitespace at all below the x-axis point labels, or to the left of the y-axis point labels, etc.

By the way, when inserting into a LaTeX document, I will always use `standAlone=F` in the `tikz` command above and then use `\input{binomial}` in the document. There is no difference in whitespace as can be easily verified by `\framebox{\input{binomial}}`. Also, `par(xaxs='i')` made no difference.

Does any know of anyway where I can remove all the whitespace from the margins of these plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before the `barplot`:

```
op <- par(mar = rep(1, 4))
```

Where `1` is a margin. It's counted from the axes, so `0` would strip the ticks. Try several, `1.8` is OK for me for you plot.

Answer (score 2):

Try `op <- par(cex=0.5)` before the `barplot`, but after the `tikz` command. You can also modify the size of the title, the axis annotation and the labels of the axis by adding `cex.main=` ..., `cex.axis=` ... or `cex.lab=` ...,
respectively. These numbers get multiplied by `cex`.